# default queue for interactive job with torque

Tags: pbs, torque

As a Torque administrator, how can I force interactive jobs to be part of a given queue (let say 'interactive_queue') while keeping another default queue for non-interactive jobs. In other words, I'd like the command:

```
qsub -I
```

to be equivalent (by default) to:

```
qsub -I -q interactive_queue
```

while keeping

```
set server default_queue = another_queue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the queue options correctly:

```
  qmgr -c "set queue another_queue disallowed_types = interactive"
  qmgr -c "set queue interactive_queue disallowed_types = batch"
```